# Getting an error while trying to pass arguments from command line

Tags: python, pathlib, typer

I am trying to create a python script file with multiple functions and pass 3 arguments to the main functions. These parameters are also passed onto other functions with the script. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
import benepar
import spacy
import json
import gc
import typer
from spacy.tokens import Doc,DocBin
from typing import Tuple, List
from pathlib import Path

def main(nlp_dir: Path,inp_File:Path,out_File:Path):
    try:
        seg_obj=load_nlp_object(nlp_dir)
        print('Loaded nlp obj')
        doc_train=DocBin().from_disk(inp_File)
        docs=get_list_of_docs(doc_train,nlp_dir)
        data=[]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    chunk_count=0
    for d in docs:
        try:
            temp=seg_obj(d)
            chunk_count=chunk_count+1  
            if chunk_count%5 == 0:
                seg_obj=load_nlp_object(nlp_dir)
                gc.collect()
            #Other code
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    #Saving linker data
    for val in data:
        with open(out_File,'a',encoding='utf8') as f:
            json.dump(val,f)
            f.write(",\n")
    print('Data created successfully.')



def load_nlp_object(nlp_dir):
    #Code
    return nlp

def get_list_of_docs(bin_obj,nl):
    n=load_nlp_object(nl)
    dcs=list(bin_obj.get_docs(n.vocab))
    return dcs

def benepar_split(doc: Doc) -> List[Tuple]:
     #Code
    return split_indices

if __name__=='__main__':
    typer.run(main)
```

While running I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\Project\create_linker_data.py", line 96, in <module>
    typer.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 864, in run
    app()
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 214, in __call__
    return get_command(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shrinidhi\Desktop\Sentiment Analysis\sentiment\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 500, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inp_file'
```

I have debugged by code but I am unable to find the root cause. My command line command is `python create_linker_data.py "Entity Linker\\ner_obj\\" "Named Entity Recognition\\sentiment_data\\3\\3.spacy" "Entity Linker\\data\\entity_linker_3.txt"`

Comment: `inp_file != inp_File`

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you for your response. I don't think I am passing the inp_file parameter anywhere, Wondering from where it seems to pick it up?I have updated my question with the command I am executing as well.

Comment: @PeterWood Hey!I replaced inp_File with inp_file i.e. made all the letters smallcase and it worked!I am still unclear if there is any particular nomenclature but this worked!Thank you!If you can post your comment as an answer, I can accept the same.